# time picker showing time like 5:7 instead of 05:07

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a time picker function which sets time in an EditText but the format it shows is not suitable. For example for ***04:07pm*** is shown as ***4:7***. *Whenever the digit in **time is less than 10 it removes the 0** automatically*.

Please help me out. My code is

```
$("#startTime").kendoTimePicker();
var timepicker = $("#startTime").data("kendoTimePicker");
timepicker.enable(true);
StartTimeVal = $('#startTime').val("");
```

Comment: use format :  format: "hh:mm tt"

Comment: Thank you JYothi it has worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `format` you can format the time using `format` option like this

```
$("##startTime").kendoTimePicker({
        format: "hh:mm tt"
    });
```